# How to start an empty thread using c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I have this code after start up program:

```
#include <thread> 
using namespace std;

thread _thread;
```

I want set up variable `_thread` later and call `sayHello` function. How can I do this?

```
void sayHello() {
   //some hello code :-)
}
```

Sure, I can call `thread _someName(sayHello);` but I want call "start thread" later.

Thanks for your help.

Easily:

```
thread _thread;
_thread = //how to start ?
```

Comment: Nor C++ language, nor standard library has functionality to achieve this.

Comment: @SergeyA: either you're wrong, or one of us misunderstands the question...

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, if you think I am wrong, you can provide an answer :)

Comment: Not help me, I am getting syntaxt errrors. No instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list

Comment: @jiofriau Using the default constructor of `std::thread` is just fine, you can move another thread with a thread function parameter later.

Comment: attempting to reference a deleted function kernel